# How do I change variable in a function from another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code like this:

```
//app.js
var r=require("./second.js");
var a=1;
r.second(a);
console.log(a);
```

And my second.js looks like this:

```
//second.js
module.exports.change=function(a){
    a=2;
}
```

Currently console.log(a) only show 1, I did a bit of research saying I can't pass it as a variable because variable is passed as value. I thought about using global.a. However, it doesn't work too because a is stored as a module variable, not a global variable, and I don't want to set it as a global variable.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, there isn't any function that is called `second`. Your module exposes a function called `change`. Then when you pass a value to function this value is copied and whatever change you do affects only the copy. So passing the value of `a`, the change affects only the copy of this value and not the original one. What could you do is to pass an object. This time a copy of the reference to the object is passed. So any change you make is reflected back to the original object (it's like pointers in C and C++).

In terms of code, the changes you should make are the following:

```
// You could make the method more dynamical passing the value you want a get.
module.exports.change = function(obj, value){
    obj.a = value;
}
```

Last you should call it as:

```
var r=require("./second.js");
var obj = { a: 1};
r.change(obj,2);
console.log(obj.a);
```

Answer (score 6):

The main answer is that you can't do it exactly as you asked.  A variable defined as you have `a` in app.js is private to the scope of `a` and only other code within app.js can modify it.

There are a number of other ways you can structure things such that module B can modify something in module A or cause something to be modified in module A.

### Global

You can make `a` global.  This is not recommended for a variety of reasons.  But you could make it a property of the global object by changing your declaration of `a` to:

```
global.a = 1;
```

Then, in module B, you can directly set:

```
global.a = 2;
```

### Pass and Return

You can pass `a` into a function in module B and have that function return a new value that you assign back into `a`.

```
const b = require('moduleB');

let a = 1;
a = b.someFunction(a);
console.log(a);    // 2
```

Then, inside of moduleB, you can modify propertys on `a` directly:

```
// inside of moduleB
module.exports.someFunction = function(a) {
    return ++a;
};
```

### Put value in object and pass reference to object

Rather than storing the value in a simple variable, you can store it as a property of an object an you can then pass a reference to that object.  Objects in Javascript are passed by ptr so some other function you pass the object to can modify its properties directly.

```
const b = require('moduleB');

let a = {someProperty: 1};

b.someFunction(a);
console.log(a.someProperty);    // 2
```

Then, inside of moduleB, you can modify propertys on `a` directly:

```
// inside of moduleB
module.exports.someFunction = function(obj) {
    obj.someProperty = 2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**First way** is return in your `change` function in `second.js`.

app.js:

```
var r=require("./second.js");
var a=1;
a = r.change(a);
console.log(a);
```

second.js:

```
module.exports.change=function(a){
    a=2;
    return a;
}
```

**Second way** is use object as parameter to pass it by reference:

app.js:

```
var r=require("./second.js");
var obj={a:1};
r.change(obj);
console.log(obj.a);
```

second.js:

```
module.exports.change=function(obj){
    obj.a=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage or sessionStorage for setting and getting your variable.
for node js you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/localStorage package

```
//You can set using localStorage.setItem('key','value')

var r = require("./second.js");
var a = 1;
localStorage.setItem('a', 1) /*Window api for setting variable locally 
localStorage.setItem('key','value')*/
r.second(a);
console.log(a);
```

You can get using localStorage.getItem('key')

```
//second.js
module.exports.change=function(a){
a=localStorage.getItem('a')
}
```